# How to fill curve only up to a certain value, simultaneously with line gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot with filled curved only until when the value on the column one are less than zero. How should I do? Maybe plot two different line each time with different range?

My code is:

```
 p "data.txt"  ($1 <=0  ? $2 : 1/0) w filledcurves , '' ($1 <=0    ? $2 : 1/0) w filledcurves, \
 ...
```

But this way the value on the x-axis are wrong and the curve filled in a wrong strange way:
[image]

---

In this other way the x-axis are right while the curve still filled up in a werid way:

```
plot 'data.txt' u 1:($1<=0?$2:1/0)
```

[image]

Are those a bug in gnuplot?

While I would be something like this but filled up only until zero:
[image]

There is also a way to simultaneously plot with line, and select the line style?

Comment: Thank you, much clearer now. So, then does Tom Solid's response answer your question?

Comment: SOLUTION: plot 'data.txt' u 1:($1<=40?$2:1/0) w filledcurves y=0, '' u  1:($1>40?$2:1/0) w l lc 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems:

**1** - You should use `using` or `u` like:

```
plot "data.txt" u ($1 <=0  ? $2 : 1/0)
```

**2** - In this form you plot the 2nd column (or nothing; depending on the 1st column) aganist the 0th column (which (nearly) equals to the line number). To examine this effect, try and see:

```
plot "data.txt" u 2
```

**3 - ANSWER:** the correct syntax is like:

```
plot 'data.txt' u ($1<=0?$1:1/0):2
```

or

```
plot 'data.txt' u 1:($1<=0?$2:1/0)
```

which depends on what do you want to plot actually. The difference between them that the first one sets the `xrange` of the plot up to 0 while the second one displays a wider `xrange` (up to x_max of your data). However, in your case, you could use both of them. (Or you can mix them.) Eg.:

```
plot 'data.txt' u 1:($1<=40?$2:1/0) w filledcurves y=0, '' u  1:($1>40?$2:1/0) w l lc 1
```

[image: example]

The problem with your plot was that using a 'naked' `filledcurves` with a 2 column data set, the default option is `closed` which threats the dataset as a closed polygon.

Comment: plot 'data.txt' u 1:($1<=40?$2:1/0) w filledcurves y=0, '' u  1:($1>40?$2:1/0) w l lc 1 works.